# How to retrieve datastores in VMWARE based on the cluster name

Tags: pyvmomi

How to retrieve datastores in VMWARE based on the cluster name using Pyvmomi.
[vim.Storagepod] gives null result, so is there any other way to retrieve the datastores filtering on the datacluster name.

datastores = get_all_objs(content, vim.StoragePod)
It returns a null object

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. You need to use:

```
    datastores = get_all_objs(content, [vim.StoragePod])
```

Comment: When i refer the cluster, its not datatstore cluster name. It is the site under the datacenter. Is it possible to retrieve the datastores based on site filter?

Comment: That's a different question.